# How to remove model name from URL with friendly_id in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing, rails-routing, friendly-id

I have a question model which allows users to add questions.

I have set up Friendly_id so now that when a user adds a question the url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/questions/this-is-a-question
```

However, i want the url to appear like this

```
http://localhost:3000/this-is-a-question
```

Do you have any ideas on how i can do this with friendly_id?

Thanks

UPDATE:

This is my friendly_id bit in question.rb

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

def slug_candidates
[
  :title,
  [:title, :id]
]
end

def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record?
end
```

end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in routes.rb

```
resources :questions, path: ''
```

throws errors when you are logged out.

try:

```
get '/:friendly_id', to: 'questions#show'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in routes.rb

```
resources :questions, path: ''
```

Comment: There is no errors, but the 'question' is still in the URL. i have another resource, resources :questions do resources :answers end. Any ideas?

Comment: so change there - resources :questions, path: '' do resources :answers end

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your response. This gives a no route error when there is a route...Is there a way to do this in friendly_id? Any other ideas? Cheers

Comment: Did you try the url 'http://localhost:3000/this-is-a-question' directly in the browser

Comment: I have an error! While this works whilst a user is signed in. When i try to logout i get the error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound on the line: def set_question
      ATquestion = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

Comment: It record not found error.check  if the record with that id exists using console

Answer (score 1):

In routes.rb

```
resources :questions, except: :show # Remove others you don't want

get ':id', to: 'questions#show', as: 'question'
```

Please make sure that you use friendly_id's reserved words if you are using a root level id. Also, make sure that you keep the `get ':id', to: 'questions#show', as: 'question'` line at the bottom of your routes.rb so that everything else is prioritized above it. It's a dangerous route.

Comment: hmmm...i did everything you said but got this error. Invalid route name, already in use: 'question' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources'. On this line: get ':title', to: 'questions#show', as: 'question'

Comment: Try commenting out the `resources :questions` bit for a minute and see if that helps. When you are setting the route `as: 'question'`, that is basically telling it to overwrite the `question_path` route. The issue is that it still thinks `resources :question, only: :show` is still around.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried that but still no good! Is there any other way of doing this? Maybe in the question model with friendly_id?

Answer (score 0):

What you want in your `routes.rb` is something similar to below:

```
get '/:id', to: 'posts#show', constraints: { id: /\d.+/ }
get '/:username', to: 'users#show'
```

copied from the routing documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

in your case if the question name is called `friendly_id`, then what you want is:

```
get '/:friendly_id', to: 'questions#show'
```

and in your `controller show method` you would be using `param[:friendly_id]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I added the line to my routes.rb and it worked i didn't change the controller as this was failing when changed. However, this line did not change the URL, 'question' was still there. Any ideas?

Comment: @LewisFrost, I have tested this and it works in a similar scenario, you need to try the URL directly in your browser, then log the params to the console in your controller(`logger.info params`) so see what params you are receiving, if you try this in your browser `http://localhost:3000/this-is-a-question` then your `questions#show` should be receiving `[:friendly_id => "this-is-a-question"]`, you might as well need to post some of your logs after using the route I specified